Can one compute the automorphism group of a curve of genus >1?
Given a sufficiently nice perfect field $k$ and a smooth projective curve $C$ of genus $g_C>1$ over $k$, can one compute the automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(C)$? It is known that ${\rm Aut}(C)$ is always finite, e.g. of order at most $84(g-1)$ if ${\rm char}(k)=0$. The crucial case seems to be that of $k$ algebraically closed, and to determine the group it should be enough to know its order. So for concreteness let me ask:
Question: Is there an algorithm that takes $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ as input which defines a geometrically integral plane curve $f(X,Y)=0$ with smooth projective model $C$ of genus $g_C>1$, and outputs $n_f:=|{\rm Aut}(C_\mathbb{C})|$, the order of the automorphism group of $C$ over $\mathbb{C}$?
Remarks:

I am not asking for an efficient algorithm, just whether the function $f\mapsto n_f$ is computable. I expect that the answer is YES and that this is known, but I could not find a reference.
It seems that MAGMA can compute ${\rm Aut}(C)$ for curves of genus $g_C>1$ over certain base fields, which includes algebraically closed fields when the curve is hyperelliptic.
If I understand Theorem 30 in [1] correctly, when the plane curve $C: f=0$ is already smooth, all of its automorphisms are linear and so it is possible to count them. For the general case any such bound on the degrees should suffice.

[1] J. Kollár, Algebraic hypersurfaces, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 2019, https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2019-56-04/S0273-0979-2019-01663-2/S0273-0979-2019-01663-2.pdf

For a smooth projectively normal curve of genus $g$ and degree $d$, every automorphism can be presented with a tuple of polynomials of degree $1+ \lceil \frac{g}{d} \rceil$ since by Riemann-Roch $\mathcal O(  1+ \lceil \frac{g}{d} \rceil) \otimes \sigma^* \mathcal O(-1)$ has a section and multiplying the pullback under $\sigma$ of the linear system corresponding to the embedding inside $H^0( C,\mathcal O(1))$ by such a section produces the desired tuple. If the curve is not projectively normal maybe you need a higher bound on the degree...

F. Hess, An algorithm for computing isomorphisms of algebraic function fields, Algorithmic number theory, Lecture Notes in Comput. Sci., vol. 3076, Springer, Berlin, 2004, pp. 263–271,

perfect, thank you!
